# How to get MAC Address of client?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mac-address

I am trying to get the MAC address of the client pc but it shows the mac address of the IIS server where my project is hosted.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NetworkInterface[] anics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
        foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in anics)
        {
            if (amacaddress == String.Empty)
            {
                IPInterfaceProperties properties = adapter.GetIPProperties();
                amacaddress = adapter.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
                lblname.Visible = true;
                string ip = Request.UserHostAddress;

                lblname.Text = "MAC Address is :- " + amacaddress + "  "+ ip;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't get the MAC address of a client natively. Even if you could access that part of the network request (actually you might be, I'm not sure on that), it wouldn't be the MAC address of the client, but of the last hop in the network on the packets way to your server.

Comment: You typically cannot get the MAC address of the client in C#, or *ANY* language. That's just not how TCP/IP works; that's not how communication between different networks connected by routers works.

Comment: Your comment flag has been declined. Please read about [how to flag comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373801/when-is-a-comment-hostile-or-unfriendly-educating-newer-users-how-to-flag-comm).

Comment: You cannot get the MAC address and even if you could, there's nothing you could usefully do with that information either. What problem were you trying to solve where you thought "I'll get the client's MAC address" would be part of the solution? That we might be able to help you with.

Comment: There are two answers to your Question.   1 – From an application you do not care what the Mac Address is – even if you had it – it would be the wrong one.  In today’s VM world this problem is compounded.    2 – If you want the MAC address it usually is from a management or special scenario.  Most Pc/server systems have Agents and API’s that have intimate knowledge of the MAC addresses (plural) on a system. Look up SNMP for example.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah. That is similar to asking for getting the IMSI of a phone from a phone call - not possible, you call a phone number, the rest is implementation detail. MAC Addresses pretty much never travel more than one ethernet domain (next switch/router). They are not pat of the IP protocol layer. As such, you can not get them from the http request, which ultimatly is a TCP thus an IP connection. YOu will have to execute (C#, not javascript) code on the client to possibly get the local MAC AddressES - that is plural, there may be more than one (as in: 2 local network cards, a wireless adapter = 3 mac addresses).

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining.